# continues dragging background on mouse

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I try to make infinite  background dragging on `mouseDragg` but I stuck. I want background when disappears left appear right and opposite way. I try various solutions but nothing seems to work.

```js
var StageStart = 0;
var StageEnd = 200;
var x1 = 0;
var x2 = 0;
var x=0;
var y=0;
function setup() { 
    createCanvas(200, 200);
} 

function draw() { 
    background(0);
    stroke(255, 204, 0);
    strokeWeight(4);
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    translate(x1,x2);
    rect(x, y, width, height);
}
  
function mouseDragged(){
    x1=mouseX;
    if(x1 <= -width){
        for(var i=0;i<width;i++)
            x1=StageEnd -width+ i++ ;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is an much easier way to get the drag distance. Use [`pmouseX`](https://processing.org/reference/pmouseX.html) to get the previous mouse position:

```js
dx = mouseX - pmouseX;
```

When the back ground is shifted, then the back ground has to be draw a 2nd time at the left or right of the original background:
(Note, if the background is shifted on both axis, it has to be drawn 4 times)

```js
rect(x, y, width, height);
if (x1m > 0)
    rect(x-width, y, width, height);
else if (x1m < 0)
    rect(x+width, y, width, height);
```

See the example:

```js
var StageStart = 0;
var StageEnd = 200;
var x1 = 0;
var x2 = 0;
var x=0;
var y=0;
function setup() { 
    createCanvas(200, 200);
} 

function draw() { 
    background(0);
    stroke(255, 204, 0);
    strokeWeight(4);
    fill(0, 255, 0);

    var x1m = x1 % width;
    translate(x1m, x2);
    
    rect(x, y, width, height);
    if (x1m > 0)
        rect(x-width, y, width, height);
    else if (x1m < 0)
        rect(x+width, y, width, height);
}
  
function mouseDragged(){
    dx = mouseX - pmouseX;
    x1 += dx;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have undeleted my previous question and roll back edit to this question. sorry for confusing you... Can You help me with grid translation question ?